# How to make Shopping Cart Rule work with configurable product in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, conditional-statements, rule, configurable

The condition Shopping Cart Rule in Magento doesn't match with the custom attribute of product (configurable product). So how to make it work with configurable product ? (Size 8 , men,.. ). I searched some solution but they don't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily. But you have to dig some coding. 
All you have to do use the final cusstom option sku on the shopping cart price rule.
For example if you have an t-shirt names having sku = SKUTSHIRT, and color = red, size = M,
Then the final sku will be **"SKUTSHIRT-red-M"**.

You have to use this sku on shopping cart price rule. And how to work with custom skus you can find by this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-shopping-cart-promotion-rule-for-product-with-custom-options/).

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Does the Shopping Cart Price Rule apply to all versions of the configurable product? If so, you could also group them in a Category (which you exclude from nav) and use that category for the Price Rule.

This workaround works pretty easy and straight forward (if the catalog size is not too big, to keep workarounds manageable).